# Collision resolution technique in custom hasmap implementation

Tags: data-structures, hashmap

This was for an interview . 
They asked me what would be a good way to implement a custom hashmap.

To which i answered, if you have an array of say , n , elements.

you can have an individual key mapped to an integer for index %n.
This would let you store the key in the hashmap. But
if there is a collision, then you could keep a list of Values in the custom array.
Now the worse case for using a list in custom hashmap like this is O(n).
So , I suggested , we could use a Heap (min-heap) inside the list and call heapify() 
to balance it.This also would give a logn complexity?

Another thing that came to my mind, is i could use a Tree with 2-3-4 nodes , thus the logn complexity would be reduced. (Something like a B+ tree)

Any better ideas to resolve collisions in case of a custom heap implementation?

Comment: The heap would require O(n) in the worst, as you may have to traverse the whole heap until you find the element you need. Heaps don't provide a general lookup algorithm. The tree suggestion would constrain the keys to be somehow ordered, and the ordering has to be consistent with the hash function and the equality relation.

Answer (score 1):

Most commonly you resolve the hashmap collision via:

1. deque (how PHP does it)
2. linked list
3. actually, just increment the hashed value until you find a slot that isn't a collision.

For the first example, to store the key "hello" with the value "world", you'd get the integer hashmap key via your hash function (assuming C/C++ implementation):

```
// the following is given: that there is some object "myvalue"
// where myvalue.value = "world", and myvalue.key = "hello".
int hash_key = hash(myvalue.key); //myvalue.key = "hello", as given
```

then insert the value into the deque element at index `hash_key`:

```
hash_map[hash_key].push_back(myvalue);
```

where `hash_map` is your N-index array of deques, and `myvalue` is the object to insert (note that `myvalue` should have its own `key` member set to "hello" so it can be retrieved later).

To find an item in the hash map, you hash the key ("hello"), and then traverse the deque until you find the item.  If the digest space of your hash function is sufficiently large (say, a 32-bit unsigned integer = 4 billion unique hash results) and your hash function gives a uniform distribution, then the odds of a collision are small enough (1 in 2^32) that your deque will likely only have 1 or 2 items (even if you're storing 2^33 items), and a fancier structure (AVL tree, RB tree, whatever) slows the data structure more than it helps.

You'll almost absolutely run out of memory storing items before collisions and the slowness of a linear search become a limiting factor.

(EDITED TO ADD: You don't have to [and shouldn't, for large hash function spaces] pre-allocate the entire hash map.  Use a deque for that as well, so that it grows as the number of hash results grow.)

Comment: If N = 2^32, you need that many pointers to represent an empty hash table. That's 32GB on an x86-64.

Comment: My assumption was that (I didn't write the code for it 'cause I'm lazy) you only create the deques when they're first referenced, and you create the hash_map as a deque itself or an int ** (array of arrays) where you instantiate pages for the hash pointers as necessary, or something more clever.  I'll leave that exercise to the person who actually wants to code it. Even if N = 2^16 (only 500KB of memory space on x86-64) would still yield a distribution of 1/65536 items, so a depth of ~15 items/deque per 1,000,000 items hashed. O(M) where M = 15 is pretty small :)

Answer (score 1):

The usual trick (at least, this is how Python and Java both do it) is to resolve collisions by putting dynamic arrays or linked lists in the hash buckets, as you suggest. In addition, the hash table gets a parameter called the *maximum load factor*, which is e.g. 2/3. When the load factor gets higher than its allowed maximum (the table is more than 2/3 full), a [new hash table is allocated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Dynamic_resizing) that is, say, twice as large as the original one and all the data is moved into that new hash table.

While the copying can be expensive, its cost can be [amortized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) over the lookups.